# Is there a benefit to buying landmarks?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations, assassins-creed-brotherhood

Is there a reason or benefit to buy landmarks? Do they generate income or is there some other benefit?

If they generate income, is that income based on the cost of the landmark, or a fixed income?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Landmarks generate income, but they're generally super expensive compared to the income they generate, especially compared to other buildings and shops.  Focus on buying other things first, and then when you have way too much cash floating around, pick up the landmarks.

Answer (score -4):

Get the other stuff first, and it's pretty useless unless you're going for 100% completion. But they do generate income, vey little compared to the prices